# Adding .htaccess makes Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp, internal-server-error

Hi I am trying to remove the `.php` extension from the url . For that I am following this tutorial [remove .php extension](http://sicanstudios.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/) . But when I add the `.htaccess` file to the directory , it shows

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

My `.htaccess` file is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Whats wrong?

NB: I am testing all my files in WAMP server.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Have you checked the `apache error log` use the wampmanager menus to view it like this `left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Apache error log`

Answer (score 1):

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
line is the major reason of that error 
please comment it as

```
#Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

error will remove

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem you need to enable `mod rewrite`
Open terminal and print `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
Then restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `#` before the below line.

Before Edit

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

After Edit

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```